# Using Django-taggit and django-taggit-serializer with issue

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-taggit

I am trying to add tags in my model by taggit and taggit serializer. I making my API in rest framework. 
I followed the instruction（https://github.com/glemmaPaul/django-taggit-serializer） but it is still an issues:

> "tags": [
>           "Invalid json list. A tag list submitted in string form must be valid json."]

/setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  [...]
'rest_framework',
'taggit',
'taggit_serializer',
]
```

/models.py

```
tags = TaggableManager(blank = True)
```

/serializer.py

```
class JobSerializer(TaggitSerializer,serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

# tag serializer
tags = TagListSerializerField()
```

There is noting changed in the view.py.

thanks @ykh for helping me to solve this problem, but it comes to new situation with error:

when you want to initial the value:

```
hao,free
```

the outcome will be like that:

```
 "tags": [
    "hao",
    "free"
],
```

**But** when I intend to put updates into this value:
it showed the Json file in rest framework automatically:

[image]

and if you put data to your api, the result will be:

[image]

**The issue is that each time when I try to modify the instance which including the 'tag' in rest framework, brackets and line breaks were automatic attached added in 'tag' field, like the picture result shows**

---

Update:
It seems that I have solved this issue, the solution is overriding the create function in serializer:

> using django-taggit-serializer. and

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
    tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
    instance = super(JobSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
    instance.tags.set(*tags)
    return instance
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
import six

class NewTagListSerializerField(TagListSerializerField):
    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, six.string_types):
            value = value.split(',')

        if not isinstance(value, list):
            self.fail('not_a_list', input_type=type(value).__name__)

        for s in value:
            if not isinstance(s, six.string_types):
                self.fail('not_a_str')

            self.child.run_validation(s)
        return value

class JobSerializer(TaggitSerializer,serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    tags = NewTagListSerializerField()
```

post tags with '`tags1,tags2`'

The original source code is :

```
def to_internal_value(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, six.string_types):
        if not value:
            value = "[]"
        try:
            value = json.loads(value)
        except ValueError:
            self.fail('invalid_json')

    if not isinstance(value, list):
        self.fail('not_a_list', input_type=type(value).__name__)

    for s in value:
        if not isinstance(s, six.string_types):
            self.fail('not_a_str')

        self.child.run_validation(s)

    return value
```

the error is caused by `json.loads(value)` is not success and i don't konw which data type is excepted.

Comment: I still don't understand the logic TaggitSerializer used,so I change it to meet my own requirement.

Comment: It works now, can you just briefly explain it why it doesn't work before? thx

Comment: Hi ykh, can u use to update(put) data? I got errors when using that

Comment: Thx for you patient, I have updated details into the question, general speaking, the issue is when I try to modify the instance, each time I put data, the brackets (Json format) will automatic attach on the instance, like the result shows

Comment: just remove the data  drf automatically create and use the old format to update,like newtag1,newtag2

Answer (score 1):

Correction to the answer above, because solution by Ykh works incorrect, when i want to update my tags in JSON format(i got \r \m \ symbols)

```
import json

class NewTagListSerializerField(TagListSerializerField):
    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, six.string_types):
            if not value:
                value = "[]"
            try:
                if(type(value) == str):
                    if(value.__contains__('"') == True):
                        value = json.loads(value)
                    else:
                        value = value.split(',')

            except ValueError:
                self.fail('invalid_json')

        if not isinstance(value, list):
            self.fail('not_a_list', input_type=type(value).__name__)

        for s in value:
            if not isinstance(s, six.string_types):
                self.fail('not_a_str')

            self.child.run_validation(s)

        return value
```

Comment: What was wrong with the answer above? What needed changed? Please include these details in your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this issue when writing unit tests. It's because the python dictionary that I used to store the POST data becomes internally converted into a QueryDict. This typically happens when Django considers the POST as content of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, e.g. something sent via an HTML form.

I think `TagListSerializerField` is expecting json, so when its `to_internal_value` is called, incorrect data is being received and it fails with the "Invalid json list..." error.

In short, this is what I had to do.

```
data = {"tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]}
response = self.client.post('/api/endpoint/', json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

In other words, the data needs to be converted to json, and the content type has to be set.
In my example, `self.client` is a `APIClient` from from `rest_framework.test`.