# django rest framework , Invalid json list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-taggit

I am trying to add tags to my posts. It works fine but whenever I make serializer class (to return JSON data ) it raises the error shown below:

```
 {
    "tags": [
        "Invalid json list. A tag list submitted in string form must be valid json."
    ]
}
```

I am using `django-taggit` and `django-taggit-serializer` packages.

my installed app in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'rest_framework',
   'rest_framework_gis',
   'taggit',
   'taggit_serializer'
]
```

my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

   title= models.CharField(max_length=50)
   description = models.TextField()
   location = models.PointField(srid=4326)
   tags = TaggableManager()
```

my serializers.py

```
class PostCreateSerializer(TaggitSerializer,GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        geo_field = 'location' 
        fields = [
            'title','description','tags'
         ]
```

my views.py

```
class PostCreateApiView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostCreateSerializer
    message = 'you have not account'
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self,serializer):
       serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

I have seen some similar questions but they didn't work for my case.
I use geodjango with PostGIS database. 
Data that I'm trying to add:

```
{
   "title": "my title",
   "description": "nice desc",
   "city": "city name",
   "tags": tag1 tag2 tag3,
   "location": POINT(-123.0208 44.0464)
 }
```

Comment: geo django unlikely to interfere here. What data do you post ?

Comment: whats matter , imagine its not geodjango , do have the answer ?

Comment: the answer is already given in the server response: send a list of tags, not a string. If you need more help we'll need to see what data you are sending to be sure

Comment: the data are : {
    "title": "my title",
    "description": "nice desc",
    "city": "city name",
    "tags": tag1 tag2 tag3,
    "location": POINT(-123.0208 44.0464)
}

Comment: updated the post@Linovia

Comment: Did you see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695298/using-django-taggit-and-django-taggit-serializer-with-issue)?

Comment: the problem solved , and answered this question [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52695820/13001893)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with the format the data sent in.
Try to send tags in list format, not a string.
Ex: 
`{
   "title": "my title",
   "description": "nice desc",
   "city": "city name",
   "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
   "location": POINT(-123.0208 44.0464)
 }`

check [this](https://github.com/glemmaPaul/django-taggit-serializer/blob/be5c649d54c46eb1c71731583bcaa768ad5b9aaa/taggit_serializer/serializers.py#L65) for more info about the raised exception.

Comment: try to inspect the request querydict data in the create view and make sure tags are passed as a list string not as a string.
https://github.com/glemmaPaul/django-taggit-serializer/issues/35#issuecomment-307451554